wildCard query not returning response for search
I'm implementing a search functionality which can search efficiently on millions of data in Open search in PROD env.
I have a field name in "searchInfo" in my api and we can searchany of these fields("employee_id", "employee_name","location","employee_info.external_employee_id") in this single field.
my query_string query is working
POST /employee_search_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": ["employee_id", "employee_name","location","employee_info.external_employee_id"],
      "query": "Rich*",
      "analyze_wildcard": true,
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  }
}

But WILDCARD query is not working, also search should be case-Insensitive.
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        { "wildcard": { "employee_id": { "value": "rich*" } } },
        { "wildcard": { "employee_name": { "value": "rich*" } } },
        { "wildcard": { "location": { "value": "rich*" } } },
        { "wildcard": { "employee_info.external_employee_id": { "value": "rich*"}}} 
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}

What is wrong in wildCard query?
I want to implement efficient way of partial and full search on these fields. what will be the best way of implementing partial and full search?

Are your fields case sensitive? I notice that Rich is not capitalized in your second query.

@IanGabes no search must case-insensitive

Could you share the index mapping in regards to this 4 fields and the analyzer used, please?
